# VBA, search in column for specific character, extract string upto that character

Tags: vba, excel

In a specific column, I want to search for a specific character in cells...say "(" or "/". Once this character is found in a cell, I want to extract the part from the beginning of the string upto the point that this character is found, in the cell adjacent to it.

E.g. a few values in the column could look like -

```
Samsung (india)
Samsung/Dhamal
Blackberry (chikna)
Blackberry/Kala Anda
iPhone - egypt
iPhone 5 * yeda
```

The output will look like -

```
Samsung
Samsung
Blackberry
Blackberry
iPhone
iPhone 5
```

**NOTE:** The cell values in that specific column, are not static, have no pattern, may contain other special characters as well, are not of a specific length.

Comment: I have been trying various code combinations e.g. InStr, Mid, LEFT etc. but I can't seem to get it right. I can't get the loop definition properly coupled with how to look for a character, extract to adjacent cell, move to the next cell, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is well suited for regular expressions. The following function returns the position of the character preceding the first match of a simple regex pattern in a given string. If no match is found, the function returns the length of the string. The function can be combined with the LEFT function to extract the text preceding the match. (*The use of LEFT is necessary because, for the sake of simplicity, this function does not implement submatches.*)

The following formula would extract the product names in your sample data:

```
  =LEFT(A1,regexmatch(A1," \(|\/| -| \*"))
```

Breaking down the match pattern `" \(|\/| -| \*"`:

```
  " \("  matches a space followed by a left parenthesis 
         [the backslash escapes the "(", a special character in regular expressions] 

  "|"    signifies an alternative pattern to match

  "\/"   matches a forward slash (/)

  " -"   matches a space followed by a dash (-)

  " \*"  matches a space followed by an asterisk (*).
```

To learn more about regular expressions, see this [regular expression tutorial](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm), one of many available on the web.

In order for the function to work, you will need to set a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5. To do this, select Tools/References from the VBA IDE and check this item, which will be well down the long list of references.

```
  Function regexMatch(text As String, rePattern As String)
      'Response to SO post 16591260
      'Adapted from code at http://www.macrostash.com/2011/10/08/
      '    simple-regular-expression-tutorial-for-excel-vba/.

      Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
      Dim matches As Variant

      regEx.pattern = rePattern
      regEx.IgnoreCase = True 'True to ignore case
      regEx.Global = False    'Return just the first match

      If regEx.Test(text) Then
         Set matches = regEx.Execute(text)
         regexMatch = matches(0).FirstIndex
      Else
         regexMatch = Len(text)
      End If

  End Function
```

The following subroutine applies the string extraction to each cell in a specified data column and writes the new string to a specified result column. Although it would be possible to just call the function for each cell in the data column, this would incur the overhead of compiling the regular expression (which applies to all cells) each time the function was called. To avoid this overhead,  the subroutine splits the match function in to two parts, with the pattern definition outside the loop through the data cells, and the pattern execution inside the loop.

```
  Sub SubRegexMatch()
      'Response to SO post 16591260
      'Extracts from string content of each data cell in a specified source
      '   column of the active worksheet the characters to the left of the first
      '   match of a regular expression, and writes the new string to corresponding
      '   rows in a specified result column.
      'Set the regular expression, source column, result column, and first
      '   data row in the "parameters" section
      'Regex match code was adapted from http://www.macrostash.com/2011/10/08/
      '   simple-regular-expression-tutorial-for-excel-vba/

      Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, _
          matches As Variant, _
          regexMatch As Long     'position of character *just before* match
      Dim srcCol As String, _
          resCol As String
      Dim srcRng As Range, _
          resRng As Range
      Dim firstRow As Long, _
          lastRow As Long
      Dim srcArr As Variant, _
          resArr() As String
      Dim i As Long

      'parameters
      regEx.Pattern = " \(|\/| -| \*"    'regular expression to be matched
      regEx.IgnoreCase = True
      regEx.Global = False               'return only the first match found
      srcCol = "A"                       'source data column
      resCol = "B"                       'result column
      firstRow = 2                       'set to first row with data

      With ActiveSheet
          lastRow = .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, srcCol).End(xlUp).Row
          Set srcRng = .Range(srcCol & firstRow & ":" & srcCol & lastRow)
          Set resRng = .Range(resCol & firstRow & ":" & resCol & lastRow)
          srcArr = srcRng
          ReDim resArr(1 To lastRow - firstRow + 1)
          For i = 1 To srcRng.Rows.Count
              If regEx.Test(srcArr(i, 1)) Then
                  Set matches = regEx.Execute(srcArr(i, 1))
                  regexMatch = matches(0).FirstIndex
              Else
                  regexMatch = Len(srcArr(i, 1)) 'return length of original string if no match
              End If
              resArr(i) = Left(srcArr(i, 1), regexMatch)
          Next i
          resRng = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(resArr) 'assign result to worksheet
      End With
  End Sub
```

Comment: nice chuff.  I am very new to regEx stuff so I did not even think about doing that in Excel.  +1

Comment: @chuff - could you kindly help me recast this as a subroutine? Though I'd like to mention here that the excle formula worked just great. For the moment I've used that in the script and copy pasting the formula down ;)

Comment: How would sub be used? Possibilities: user selects a range of data & sub writes results to next column to right; sub works on fixed (i.e, hard-coded) column of data and writes results to another fixed column); sub knows what column data is in, selects to bottom of data, and writes result to a specified columne; some variant on these.

Comment: @chuff - in this scenario, sub knows what column data is in and should go to the bottom of the data, and writes result to a specified column. Please note that the number of rows will change in every run hence would deeply appreciate if you could allow for a code that will detect the number of rows the data has, and then it runs. We can use the column A to detect the number of used cells.

trust this helps. and thanks a ton for helping out.

Comment: See my expanded answer. If this solves your problem, be so good as to acknowledge that by accepting the answer.

Comment: @chuff - Thanks a ton. works like ripe cheese :) cant thank you enough. i take a bow

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

```
=IF(FIND("(",A1),LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1),IF(FIND("\",A1),LEFT(A1,FIND("\",A1)-1),""))
```

If you have more than just the two characters nest in some more IF statements.  There is a limit on how much of this you can do before hitting the iteration limit for Cell functions.

Comment: Looks like this does not take care of example items 2 & 6 - where the marker character is preceded by a space, or example 5, where match needs to be on space and digit.

Comment: @chuff correct, I just did the two he had in his original question.  If he has a large hit list of characters to weed VBA would likely be better.  But if his scope is small, something like this will work.  This is meant to be a sample, not a copy/paste do it all for him.  =)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Split()` function. Here is an example:

```vb
Dim text as String
Dim splt as Variant

text = "Samsung/Dhamal"
splt = Split(text, "/")
MsgBox splt(0)
```

Just do the same for any other character you want to split. More on this on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

The other (better?) alternative I see would be to use `InStr()` with `Left()`. `InStr()` returns the position of the first match it finds. Then you just have to crop your string. Here is an example:

```vb
Dim text as String
Dim position as Integer

text = "Samsung/Dhamal"
position = InStr(text, "/")

If position > 0 then MsgBox Left(text, position)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: As an addendum, this sample is just showing the split function.  For what the OP wants to do he would also have to loop through all the needed cells and populate the adjacent column.

Comment: Obvisouly, but *this is meant to be a sample, not a copy/paste do it all for him.*

Comment: Question, I don't know VBA.  Is `position > 0` valid on a string?

Comment: Position should be an integer. Corrected. mehow's solution is a lot more robust anyway as the OP looks like he wants to track more than 2 characters here.

Comment: @dnLL -my problem is that the source text is dyanmic. As mentioned in the example, it will change for each cell. Let's say for the moment, I'd want to look for "(" or "/" characters in the cell, if found, then the adjacent cell should be filled with string from the beginning till the position the first time we come across "(" or "/". Any suggestions????

Comment: @Kinchit I assume at some point that you have some programmatic knowledge. Obviously, the source isn't an hardcoded string, it will be whatever you want from a cell to a full-column. mehow's solution does implement a loop through a range of cells. You should be able to work something out of those answers by yourself (suit it to your will).

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
Public Function IsAlphaNumeric(sChr As String) As Boolean
    IsAlphaNumeric = sChr Like "[0-9A-Za-z]"
End Function

Sub LeftUntilNonAlphaNumericChar()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim NumCharsLeftOfNonAlphaNumChar As Long
    Set colRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1000") 'specify range

    For Each cell In colRng
        If Len(cell.Text) > 0 Then
            MyString = cell.Value
            For Counter = Len(cell.Text) To Counter Step -1
                If IsAlphaNumeric(cell.Characters(Counter, 1).Text) = False And cell.Characters(Counter, 1).Text <> " " Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(cell.Value, Counter - 1)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

It doesn't remove trailing whitespaces on the end but a simple addition to the sub could change that if you wanted. Good Luck.

**ADDITION:**
You can get the row of the last cell with data in a column and use that in your range(see below):

```
Public Function IsAlphaNumeric(sChr As String) As Boolean
    IsAlphaNumeric = sChr Like "[0-9A-Za-z]"
End Function

Sub LeftUntilNonAlphaNumericChar()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim NumCharsLeftOfNonAlphaNumChar As Long

    Dim LastRow As Long
    If Application.Version >= 12# Then
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1048575").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'MsgBox "You are using Excel 2007 or greater."
    Else
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65535").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'MsgBox "You are using Excel 2003 or lesser."
    End If
    Set colRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow) 'specify range

    For Each cell In colRng
        If Len(cell.Text) > 0 Then
            MyString = cell.Value
            For Counter = Len(cell.Text) To Counter Step -1
                If IsAlphaNumeric(cell.Characters(Counter, 1).Text) = False And cell.Characters(Counter, 1).Text <> " " Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(cell.Value, Counter - 1)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this. i have a small question to ask of you. I know only the column that the data will lie in. But the data set changes and hence we dont know what the range will be. Any modifications we can make to the above code that will help keep the code dynamic?

Comment: @Kinchit See the addition above. You can just google "lastrow method excel" if you need more examples.