# Reading data from text file and delimiting

Tags: vba, excel, text-files, csv

I have an Excel 2010 spreadsheet, and I am reading in information from a .txt file (and another .xls file in future).

This text file has 3 elements per row; firtname, surname and Job title, and each element is separated by a comma. I have the data reading and pasting into Excel, however each row is pasted into the one cell. I am looking to paste each element into different columns. I know that I should try and delimit, but I just can't figure out the syntax.

My question is how do I separate each element and paste it into it's own cell? I currently use commas to separate each element on my .txt file, but future files might use tabs, full-stops, semi-colons etc. How do I extend it so all bases are covered?

Below is my code, and under my code is a sample of dummy data

```
Sub FetchDataFromTextFile()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LineText As String
    Open "C:\mytxtfile.txt" For Input As #24
    i = 2
    While Not EOF(24)
        Line Input #24, LineText
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = LineText
        P = Split(Record, ",")
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    Close #24
End Sub
```

John, Doe, Boss

Johnny, Steele, Manager

Jane, Smith, Employee

NOTE: Competant in other programming languages, however not done VB in about 6 or 7 years. I can never seem to wrap my head around VB Syntax, so please treat me like a novice for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub FetchDataFromTextFile()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LineText As String
    Open "C:\mytxtfile.txt" For Input As #24
    i = 2
    While Not EOF(24)
        Line Input #24, LineText
            Dim arr
            arr = Split(CStr(LineText), ", ")
            For j = 1 To 
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = arr(j - 1)
            Next j
            i = i + 1
    Wend
    Close #24
End Sub
```

For [different delimiters, make use of the answers in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587077/vba-search-in-column-for-specific-character-extract-string-upto-that-character/16588396#16588396)

Comment: Missing something on `For j = 1 To ... `

Comment: At `For j = 1 To`, the rest of the code is the number of columns to import. That is, `For j = 1 To 7`. Just an FYI for those who were lost like me.