# VBA to read in tab delimited file

Tags: ado

I have some code which reads in a tab delimited file where cell reference B2 matches the reference in the first column in the tab delimited file. This works fine where the text file is small. The below works on a sample file with aa bb and cc as the headers with dummy data.

```
Option Explicit
```

Sub TestImport()
    Call ImportTextFile(Sheet1.Range("B1"), vbTab, Sheet2.Range("A4"))
End Sub

Public Sub ImportTextFile(strFileName As String, strSeparator As String, rngTgt As Range)
    Dim lngTgtRow As Long
    Dim lngTgtCol As Long
    Dim varTemp As Variant
    Dim strWholeLine As String
    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim intNextPos As Integer
    Dim intTgtColIndex As Integer

```
Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = rngTgt.Parent

intTgtColIndex = rngTgt.Column
lngTgtRow = rngTgt.Row

Open strFileName For Input Access Read As #1

While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, strWholeLine

    varTemp = Split(strWholeLine, strSeparator)

If CStr(varTemp(0)) = CStr(Range("B2")) Then
                wks.Cells(lngTgtRow, intTgtColIndex).Resize(, UBound(varTemp) + 1).Value = varTemp
                lngTgtRow = lngTgtRow + 1
    End If


Wend

Close #1
Set wks = Nothing
```

End Sub

I am trying to get the below bit of code to work using ADO as this will run much faster on a text file with a couple of million records however I am getting an error on the '.Open str' part of the code (no value given for one or more required parameters).

It looks like it is to do with how I am defining the string- could you review and see if there is something I am missing...?

```
Sub QueryTextFile()
t = Timer
Dim cnn As Object
Dim str As String
Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
cnn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Users\Davids Laptop\Documents\Other Ad Hoc\Test Files\;Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"""
cnn.Open

Dim rs As Object
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
str = "SELECT * FROM [test1.txt] WHERE [aa]=" & Chr(34) & Range("B2") & Chr(34)

With rs
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .Open str
    Sheet1.Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset rs
    .Close
End With

cnn.Close
MsgBox Timer - t
```

End Sub

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668090/reading-data-from-text-file-and-delimiting

Comment: Note this post is now solved