# VBA: Insert specific file into predetermined location on worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, insert

New to VBA and trying to teach myself some simple macros to speed up some data tasks. I have a series of .txt files containing 2 tab delimited columns for time and observation (although these are recorded by our detectors as Filename and Label, respectively). I wish to create a macro to button choosing a file, and then inserting this file into a premade table. Once they are in this table I have other sheets that self populate and convert things into useful units ("time" is in the detector format, so it currently looks like R9061824.02#, hence the array). Basically this workbook would function as an analysis template.

So far I have compiled a very basic code to open a given file by modifying a recording, but this creates a new workbook.

```
ChDir "C:\"
fName = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    fName, Origin:=1257, _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
    , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Would somebody be able to help me insert this into the active workbook? The sheet I want is called Input.

Thank you!

Comment: Some [similar Q&A's](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+load+csv). (Process would be the same for as loading a CSV to a specific location.)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16668538/4717755) for help in reading delimted data from a text file