# Excel VBA - import multiple text files into same workbook with "~" delimited values

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to VBA coding so I might be doing it completely wrong.  This is some code I found online and have modified for my purpose.

I need to import 4x text files into the same workbook.
These text files have no headers, so I would like to import the text into different pre-existing worksheets which have headers.
The code I have works fine to import the text and delimit the special character, however it opens into a new spreadsheet and I can only do it once.

I need a dialog box for user to select the files and a prompt in the dialog box to indicate to the user which file to import.
    For example, the first file says "select previous SVCORPNS file", second file says "select previous MODELS file", third file says "select current SVCORPNS file", fourth file says "select current MODELS file".
The delimited value is ~.

I need a way to loop through to select the 4 text files.
I can add the headers later i it is not possible to import into pre-exisiting worksheets.

I have tried macro recording and using power query which is great but I don't know how to open to change the code for a dialog box for the user to select the file.

```
Sub Macro11()
'
' Macro11 Macro
'
'Imports a text file
Dim vFileName

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

 vFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt", , "select previous SVCORPNS file")

'If the user pressed "Cancel" or didn't select a text file, exit the procedure.
If vFileName = False Then
   GoTo BeforeExit
End If

'Switch off screen updating for speed.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'We now import the selected text file
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=vFileName, _
    Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=2, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="~~", _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=False, Local:=True

'Just to show how we auto adjust the width of column A.
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

BeforeExit:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
ErrorHandle:MsgBox Err.Description
Resume BeforeExit
'
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This question covers what you want to do - just change the delimiter in the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668090/reading-data-from-text-file-and-delimiting

Comment: It doesnt cover it because the answer is not complete

Answer (score 0):

OK here's a more "complete" example:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim vFileName, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'for example

    'load a file
    vFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt", , _
                                            "select previous SVCORPNS file")
    If Len(vFileName) > 0 Then
        PutDataFromTextFile wb.Sheets("SVCORPNS").Range("A2"), vFileName, "~"
    End If

    'load another file
    vFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt", , _
                                            "select previous MODELS file")
    If Len(vFileName) > 0 Then
        PutDataFromTextFile wb.Sheets("MODELS").Range("A2"), vFileName, "~"
    End If


    'load more files to more places....

End Sub


'Read in a delimited file from "fPath", split each row on "delim", 
'      and put the content onto a sheet starting at "rngDest".
' ## Does not handle cases where a field value can contain the delimiter
'      such as for csv where there is "hello, world" as a quoted field value
Sub PutDataFromTextFile(rngDest As Range, fPath, delim As String)
    Dim i As Long, fnum As Integer
    Dim LineText As String, arr

    fnum = FreeFile
    i = 0
    Open fPath For Input As #fnum
    While Not EOF(fnum)
        Line Input #fnum, LineText
        arr = Split(CStr(LineText), delim)
        rngDest.Offset(i, 0).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    Close #fnum
End Sub
```