# How can I tell whether the saved values are encrypted or decrypted?

Tags: .net, vba, ms-access, vbscript, vb6

I have managed to build something into a bound MS Access form that encrypts names as per client's request. This process also decrypts the data. I need a catch all that looks at what is in the input and then decrypts or encrypts the data.

Pretty sure there is something that can loop through the name and tell if it is regular word/letters or not.

Here is un-encrypted name:
Mugger Teresa

here is what it looks like encrypted:
µ`›±¤à   ¬pŽ³²ó

I'm almost positive both are part of an ASCII character set since Unicode is not turned on.
I would just like my code to be able to take the value and say: "is encrypted" or "is not encrypted". (True/False).

Comment: I don't understand. If you encrypt something and save it to the DB, then it's encrypted. If you do that with all data, then you know it's all encrypted. Why would you need to test it?

Comment: The latter definitely isn't [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) but rather some [Windows codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) - probably 1252.  The problem is, if your program has to work in countries that use accented characters you can't reliably use the test "only contains characters with a value < 127"...

Comment: [please see this answer about the ASCII in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587077/vba-search-in-column-for-specific-character-extract-string-upto-that-character/16588396#16588396)

Comment: The later is ASCII. They are called "extended characters". The client has the ability to encrypt or decrypt a name using a button next to the input on a bound form. This allows those with the key--which is a login input right below username/password inputs--to see the value but I the designer can't and neither can any of the admins  that have dba rights to that SQL Server backend. It is a database that logs employees complaints and issues. Big ones. So I built a loop that looks for the ASC value of the character, if it is above 127, then it is encrypted. 
ASCII TABLE:http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Is the encryption method fixed? If you use an XOR "encryption" with a key, it is the same procedure to encrypt and decrypt. This will remove the need to tell whether it is encrypted or not, and just use the same method. Note that any substitution method is little more than obfuscation and can fairly easily be cracked.

Comment: Thank you Deanna. Very good summation. And yes I am using XOR and yes it is just obbuscation. And yes the same function does both. And no, it's not that simple because the client wanted a small MS Access app in the beginning so all data is through bound forms, which don't have a single event that only fires once for saves and once for displays. The project is on hold because we hadn't considered the super overbuilt search form that needs to search for names in the encrypted part. It's an hours problem. I know I can always do something to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm going to answer my own question. I didn't know it when I asked, but I knew what would work.
I was looking for a character by character loop through a string to see if any of them indicated an encrypted value.
I found that the encryption I was using changed normal text into the "extended character set" of the ASCII whatever. (normal text uses first 127 characters).
So I check in that loop if any extended characters exist.

During all this seeker suggested tagging a value onto the front when encrypting that could be checked easily. That would work.

MarkJ suggested a public boolean variable that is set unset when records are displayed or saved. Might work. Certainly valid enough to try to disprove.

Answer (score 0):

I will share one idea from the practice (not mine). Of course, it may not applicable to your case, but take a look anyway.

A time ago in an old game that used INI's exclusive, I saw that most of them (but not all) was encrypted, and all encrypted files start with "BINI" (without quotes). This way the parser know that they are encrypted.

Your case is different, as (if I get it right) only a part of (names only) are encrypted, but if you follow the idea, and if you can modify the code that encrypt/decrypt, then you can do something similar, i.e. prefix encrypted names with one or more chars, lets say for instance `Chr(128)`, and of course skip this chars in your decryption procedure.

If all this has sense and applicable at all, then your `IsEncrypted` function could be:

```
Public Function IsEncrypted(ByVal strThis As String) As Boolean
    If Asc(Mid(strThis, 1, 1)) = 128 Then IsEncrypted = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You say "The client has the ability to encrypt or decrypt a name using a button next to the input on a bound form." Can't you just track button clicks to determine whether the data is encrypted?

Just use a module-level Boolean variable bIsEncrypted. It will be False when the form first loads. In the "encrypt/decrypt" button click, just do "bEncrypted = Not bEncrypted". So every time the user clicks the button, the value toggles.

Comment: Yes. But I need to be able to tell if the value is encrypted or not because it is displayed on other forms. Search form for example. But yes, a toggle button, or boolean is an approach.

Comment: From what you've said: if the other forms read the data directly from the database, it is encrypted. If they read it from the other form, they could check the Boolean (if you make it public)

Comment: Hmm. Don't know why I am shying away from this. But, you are correct. And I have used this method at other times. Right now, boolean value, ASCII check, or boojum tree methods are mute because the search form has to search these columns with only normal text entered (first, last name).